# Show $|\det(v_1,\cdots,v_n)|=\text{vol}(v_1\cdots,v_n).$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to show that $|\det(v_1,\cdots,v_n)|=\text{vol}(v_1\cdots,v_n).$ In this case, I proved that the $|det|$ is one of the volume function of a parallelepiped (4 axioms). But I have no idea about how to show the uniqueness which is necessary in order to show the equality.
Four axioms:
$$(1)~~~ \text{vol}(e_1,\cdots,e_n)=1$$
$$(2)~~~\text{vol}(v_1,\cdots,cv_i,\cdots,v_n)=|c|\text{vol}(v_1,\cdots,v_i,\cdots,v_n)$$
$$(3)~~~\text{vol}(v_1,\cdots,v_i+cv_j,\cdots,v_n)=\text{vol}(v_1,\cdots,v_i,\cdots,v_n)$$
$$(4)~~~\text{vol}(v_1,\cdots,v_i,\cdots,v_j,\cdots,v_n)=\text{vol}(v_1,\cdots,v_j,\cdots,v_i,\cdots,v_n)$$

Comment: Are you trying to prove it with somewhat informal notion of volume? Or to prove it formally with Lebesgue measure? Moreover, what are four axioms? If you try to prove the uniqueness of translation invariant measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ **formally**, search for "pi-lambda theorem"

Comment: @Rubertos I think I only need prove it with informal notion since the question is asking using these axioms to prove that $|\det(v_1,\cdots,v_n)|=\text{vol}(v_1,\cdots,v_n).$

Answer (score 1):

Rather than operations on sets of vectors, consider the map $A \to \det (Ae_1, \dots, Ae_n) = \det A$ for a matrix $A$, where the $e_i$ form the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that both $\det$ and $\operatorname{vol}$ are invariant under conjugation. Prove the result for $A$ diagonal (this should be clear), then deal with the case of a general $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ either by continuity or using the Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then
$$
\mathrm{Vol}(e_1,\ldots,e_n)=1=\mathrm{det}(e_1,\ldots,e_n).
$$
A part the value in $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ the determinant is *completely charaterized* by the properties of multilinearity and of sign changing under permutations. So it is sufficient to prove that the (signed) volume function satisfies the same properties. As for the permutations, it easily seen that (positive) volume is invariant under permutations of the sides and moreover is zero when two sides coincide. As for the multilinearity, this is easily interpreted on geometric gorunds (the sum of two parallelepipedes with one common face). This is only a sketch.

Comment: I understand both functions satisfies the same properties. But I don't see why they are equal, i.e., the uniqueness of volume function.

Comment: Actually I was just assuming as known the following result in linear algebra: the determinant is the unique skew symmetric and multilinear function of the columns such that it is equal to 1 on the identity matrix.